# Add "the" before "of"

Tags: zero-article, headlinese, proper-nouns

I am confused with the usage of "the" before an of".

> City of Pain
>
> A City of Sadness

Why the first example does not add "a" or "the" before the word "city"?

Actually, the first one is a mission of a video game called "Far Cry 4".
The second one is a movie.

Comment: Because the first example is something akin to a proper name.  (I'm sure there's a fancy name for the scenario, but I don't know it.)  In effect, "City of pain" is the name of the city.  While, in the second case, the city has sadness, but that doesn't define it.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Are there any simple rules for choosing the definite vs. indefinite (vs. none) article?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/2031/are-there-any-simple-rules-for-choosing-the-definite-vs-indefinite-vs-none-a)

Comment: Thank you @HotLicks. I agree with the idea of "proper name".

Comment: But based on the capitalization, the reverse would be true.  That is, the second is a proper name and the first isn't. So the first would be "A city of pain" and the second would be "City of Sadness".

Comment: @BrianHitchcock, thank you fur your kind help. I've modified the capitalization.

Answer (score 2):

Answered in comments:

> Because the first example is something akin to a proper name. (I'm sure there's a fancy name for the scenario, but I don't know it.) In effect, "City of pain" is the name of the city. While, in the second case, the city has sadness, but that doesn't define it. –  Hot Licks [Jan 29 2015](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/48255/add-the-before-of#comment89722_48255)